Intergalactic instant teleportation bubbles lead to intergalactic extermination
Years ago I read a book and now I'm trying to find it again. The book was about discovering a sort of teleportation bubble or booth that allowed the person to step in and immediately appear in a corresponding bubble on another continent or even another planet. They were used to transfer people and goods over unimaginable distances. These bubbles appear to span galaxies however there was no life to be found anywhere. It turns out that shortly after the bubbles came online some sort of life-ending plague broke out on one planet and immediately spread throughout the entire series of connected worlds, resulting in catastrophic loss of life.

This reminds me of the backstory material of David Weber's "Empire from the Ashes" series.  A massive interstellar empire that collapses due to a plague outbreak that rapidly spread via teleportation infrastructure.
